# Pass a simple enum into a constructor in Java

Tags: java, constructor, enums

I am trying to learn Java. I would like to have a enum as a parameter in the constructor. But I am getting an error.

```
public class Person {

    private int age, weight, height;
    private String name;

    private enum gender {MALE, FEMALE}

    public Person(int age, int weight, int height, String name, enum gender) {
         this.age    = age;
         this.weight = weight;
         this.height = height;
         this.name   = name;
         this.gender = gender;
    }
}
```

How would I handle the gender? I've tried with just gender and that didn't work either.

Comment: `public Person(int age, int weight, int height, String name, gender aGender) {` `gender` is the type you are trying to pass in, not `enum`.  You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others. There is a difference between `enum` and `Enum`, just like there is for `class` and `Class`

Comment: What about the this.gender = gender part?

Comment: Ok thank you I just needed to change it to Enum to make it do what I wanted.

Comment: Just like all you other variables, you need to define a variable of type `gender`, `private gender aGender`, the assign it, `this.aGender = aGender`.  You `gender` `enum` is just a different type/class

Comment: No, you need to change it to `gender`, other wise you can pass in any type of `enum`

Comment: Am I missing something or should it be `public enum Gender ... `?

Comment: @Fildor That would be preferred naming convention, but it won't stop it from compiling

Comment: @MadProgrammer compiling , yes. But for someone to actually use the ctor, it should be visible outside the class, right?

Comment: @Fildor Good catch, missed that :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, you need to create field of type `gender`...

```
private gender aGender;
```

Then you need to change the constructor to take a reference to an object of type `gender`

```
public Person(int age, int weight, int height, String name, gender aGender) {
```

Then you need to assign the parameter to your field...

```
this.aGender = aGender;
```

You `gender` `enum` should also be `public`

```
public enum gender {
    MALE, FEMALE
}
```

Otherwise, no one will be able to use it

For example...

```
public class Person {

    private int age, weight, height;
    private String name;
    private gender aGender;

    public enum gender {
        MALE, FEMALE
    }

    public Person(int age, int weight, int height, String name, gender aGender) {
                 this.age = age;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.height = height;
        this.name = name;
        this.aGender = aGender;
    }
}
```

You might like to have a read through [Code Conventions for the Java TM Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconvtoc-136057.html), it will make it easier for people to read your code and for you to read others

Comment: I was just going to ask since this will be a base class the enum should be public, but you answered that before I got to ask, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you have `enum Gender` defined, you can directly pass `Gender` to constructor, change as

```
public Person(int age, int weight, int height, String name, Gender gender)
```

Answer (score 1):

The enum type you defined has name `gender`, therefore you need to pass it as

```
gender eGender
```

Just a comment. By the convention all the self defined types (class names, interface names, enum names) should begin with a capital letter.

So in this case it would be better if you named your enum type like this.

```
private enum Gender {MALE, FEMALE}
```